# How can you choose the line with the higher value in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say we have this table:

```
----------
number |name| price
----------
1     |  a |  2
----------
1     |  b |  4
----------
2     |  c |  4
----------
3     |  d |  6
----------
```

I want to pick the numbers and their highest price. So how can i select only the line with number 1, which has the higher price and not show the other one?. My problem is the second column.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Comment: Yeah but then i wont see the other numbers and their prices

Comment: `2` is higher than `4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: GROUP BY

```
select number, max(price)
from your_table
group by number;
```

If you have more columns and you want to select the row with max price, use this:

```
select *
from (select
    t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by number order by price desc) rn
from your_table t) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Ok let's say i have another column and with different values for the both items with number 1. If i then group by both of them its pointless

Comment: and you want to the value in that column corresponding to the max of the price?

Comment: Yeah i want the line with number 1 which has the highest price no matter of what the value in the other column might be

Comment: @Geddi probably better to be clearer in your original question. The first answer works for your original question just fine.

Comment: it is supposed to work with only no other function than select,from,group by or order by

Comment: @Geddi - Supposed to? How? And why ask the question then?

Comment: Never mind, i think i figured it out with your second query, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, the most efficient way to get the row with the highest `price` for each `number` is to use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (number) t.*
from t
order by number, price desc;
```